# Did anyone experience issues with Flutter_Html-Widget on Iphone?

Tags: flutter, flutter-html

I have a problem using the  flutter_html package in Flutter for Iphone devices.

Currently I´m creating an app + webpage and I made use of the above mentioned package. Everything seems to work well in the programming environment. After uploading it to my local webserver I couldn´t identify any issues, however this is not the case for Iphone devices.

All html-widgets can not be loaded for Iphones, for Ipad it is, however working properly.
Does anyone has an idea for this issue? Would appreciate any comment?

Please find below the relevant Source Code + Some Screenshots for this experimental app.

```
body: Center(
          child: Html(
            data: """
              <div style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #333;">
                <h1>HTML-Widget Beispiel</h1>
                <p>HTML-Widget - Hello World!.</p>
              </div>
            """,
            style: {
              "h1": Style(
                fontSize: FontSize(24.0),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              "p": Style(
                fontSize: FontSize(18.0),
              ),
            },
          ),
        ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7iSz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2fQH.png)